# Le « election denialism » : est-ce une forme de « dénialisme » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, usage, comparaison-de-langues

Le titre d'une [manchette](https://www.cnn.com/2020/11/10/media/right-wing-media-election-denialism/index.html) contenait le terme « election denialism ». Le [*denialism*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/denialism) c'est la « [...] practice of rejecting propositions which are strongly supported by scientific or historical evidence, and often of seeking to influence policy processes and outcomes accordingly » (Wiktionary ; voir [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denialism) ; « la pratique consistant à rejeter les arguments qui sont bien étayés par des preuves scientifiques ou historiques, et souvent donc à tenter d'influencer les mécanismes d'action politique et leur résultat », ma traduction.). En français on aussi le mot [*dénialisme*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9nialisme), qui m'est inconnu, et en résumé son champ sémantique [semble moins grand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9nialisme) que celui du terme en langue anglaise :

> En langue française, le terme dénialisme a une connotation
> scientifique, contrairement au terme négationnisme qui a une
> connotation politique. Mais tous les deux s'inscrivent dans la même
> logique de déni des faits et de la réalité objective. [...] (Wikipédia, « [Dénialisme](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9nialisme) »)

Et dans l'[article en anglais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denialism#Orthodoxy_and_heterodoxy) on a une explication qui distingue le sens de *déni* de celui-là :

> Anthropologist Didier Fassin distinguishes between denial, defined as
> "the empirical observation that reality and truth are being denied",
> and denialism, which he defines as "an ideological position whereby
> one systematically reacts by refusing reality and truth". (Wikipedia, « [Denialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denialism#Orthodoxy_and_heterodoxy) »)

En résumé ça semble plus usuel en anglais, on a suffixé *denial*(ism). En français le sens plus psychologique (moins appliqué aux sciences), le « mécanisme de défense amenant à nier la réalité » semble plus restreint et son emploi est *rare* et le suffixe est presque deux fois plus long que le mot suffixé qui est morphologiquement différent ([*déni*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/d%C3%A9ni)) et où l'on préférera *dénégation* nous dit-on. Enfin c'était « election denialism », un sens plus vaste appliqué à un sujet plus précis...

Pourquoi le terme *dénialisme* (*électoral*, par exemple) convient-il ou non dans une traduction du titre de la manchette ; sinon quel mot emploierait-on ? Le terme en français a-t-il le même champ lexical, en combinant ses deux acceptions (sciences, psychologie) ou par l'extension naturelle de l'une d'entre elles, que celui en langue anglaise ; l'employer usuellement dans un contexte autre qu'en sciences constitue-t-il une extension de sens abusive ?

Comment: Réservez-le à la science, aux psy, aux amoureux des néologismes, ou pour frimer humoristiquement au second degré devant un public choisi … Comme vous le dites après « En résumé … » en voulant embrasser large sur un sujet précis le concept savant perd la puissance de *déni, dénégation*. — Pour l'article cité, je suis d'accord avec DeepL (aucune autre proposition ne convient) « Comment les médias de droite encouragent le ***négationnisme électoral*** de M. Trump  »

Comment: La ‘connotation politique’ de Wikipédia pour le négationnisme (*dénialisme*), est d'abord une perversion psychique qui nie toute réalité vérifiée trop éloignée de soi, ou qui rentre en conflit avec ses croyances ou ses intérêts et que l'on rejette car inaccessible ou non conforme à ses prévisions. On réfute, on pose alors des questions, on propose des réponses contradictoires plus ou moins vraisemblables, qui, si elles sont réfutées en engendreront d'autres en abyme. La politique est touchée par rebonds, mais c'est la science, la démocratie ou des attaques ad hominem qui en sont la source.

Comment: @Personne Intéressant. Ça pourrait aisément constituer une réponse. Merci.

Comment: C'est un choix assumé : https://french.stackexchange.com/users/848/personne?tab=profile

Comment: @Personne Je comprends mal la référence à la concurrence mais vous êtes libre et je respecte votre choix.

Comment: Dans la notion de récompenses et de bons points aux "élèves studieux" qui induit une normalisation du langage dans les réponses et ramène tout au point de vue de la grammaire, des dictionnaires … on est dans les couloirs le l'Éducation nationale, loin dans l'oralité et le partage de trouvailles ou d'approches intuitives (qui est la source de la parole)

Comment: @Personne D'accord, là je comprends. Mais justement, raison de plus de retrouver vos réponses comme contrepoids à ce nivellement. Il m'a pris un bon bout de temps à apprécier vos réponses, mais c'est le cas. Elles sont d'une grande richesse.

Answer (score 1):

Je traduirais "denialism" par "déni de réalité",
"election denialism" par "déni de résultat electoral"

Comment: Déni c'est *denial*. Du coup, a piori *denialism* ne correspond pas vraiment à déni. Il ne s'agit pas uniquement du refus d'un résultat éléctoral mais plutôt d'un refus par principe des résultat qui ne conviennent pas à la personne.

Answer (score 1):

Il s'agit ici d'un emprunt à l'anglais. De tels emprunts acquièrent souvent un sens différent de celui de leur langue d'origine, souvent spécifique au contexte où ils sont apparus. On pourrait donner comme exemples: *le mail*, *le djihad*, *le spoutnik*, *la Shoah*.

Normalement ça ne produit pas de confusion, sauf pour les personnes bilingues en français et la langue d'origine du mot. Néanmoins ici il s'agit d'un emprunt qui est très similaire à un mot français, ce qui peut produire des confusions si le mot n'est pas bien expliqué dans le contexte.

Le problème est bien connu dans le domaine de marques, où la confusion avec une marque connue est un genre de [contrefaçon de marque](https://www.journaldunet.fr/business/dictionnaire-du-droit-des-affaires/1507685-contrefacon-de-marque-definition-exemples-et-textes-de-loi/). Les recours à la justice contre des noms de marques semblables ne sont pas exceptionnels. Ici il ne s'agit pas de contrefaçon, mais on pourrais utiliser les même critères.